# ln: /usr/bin/mysql: Operation not permitted

Tags: mysql, macos

After I install the mysql in my Macbook Pro, when I excute the order:

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql /usr/bin
```

I get a error:

> Password:
>   ln: /usr/bin/mysql: Operation not permitted

---

I have tried the method below:

Method 1:

1) `vim ~/.bash_profile`
2) add `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin`

---

[image]

---

3) `source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: what has this got to do with java?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You get this error message because of Apple's System Integrity Protection. System Integrity Protection includes protection for these parts of the system:

```
/System
/usr
/bin
/sbin
Apps that are pre-installed with OS X
```

Paths and apps that third-party apps and installers can continue to write to include:

```
/Applications
/Library
/usr/local
```

This means that you can simply create a symbolic link in `/usr/local/bin` (it's still in your `$PATH`), but not in `/usr/bin`.

Also, you can disable System Integrity Protection (I strictly advise against that) by:

1. Click the  menu.
2. Select Restart...
3. Hold down command-R to boot into the Recovery System.
4. Click the Utilities menu and select Terminal.
5. Type csrutil disable and press return.
6. Close the Terminal app.
7. Click the  menu and select Restart....

Answer (score 2):

I think it's more likely that this error is not due to SIP (System Integrity Protection) but rather the Security and Privacy settings on this machine not being set up to enable Terminal.app (the terminal program) to modify this directory. This article contained the solution which worked for me (https://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/) - in System Preferenes --> Security and Privacy --> Privacy --> Full Disk access, ensure that the checkbox next to Terminal is checked (or add it).