# upgrade TLS 1.0 to TLS 1.2 on macOS

Tags: python, macos, openssl, tls1.2

I have troubles installing some python packages I believe because I have TLS 1.0 version. How do I upgrade to TLS 1.2?

```
python -c "import urllib2; import json; print(json.loads(urllib2.urlopen('https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check').read())['tls_version'])"
TLS 1.0
```

My macOS version: 10.13.4 (17E202)
python version: Python 2.7.13
openssl version: LibreSSL 2.2.7

I tried to upgrade openssl, but it does not upgrade LibreSSL. I recall I was having some issue a year ago with openssl, I might have linked it manually or something :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though brew downloaded new version of openssl, old one was used with command `openssl`. So I [disabled csrutil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42131933/2026022) to get rid of openssl symlink in `/usr/bin/openssl`:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2o_1/bin/openssl /usr/bin/openssl
```

then openssl version is the latest:

```
~ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018
```

however python still uses old version of openssl:

```
~ python -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"
OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
```

So going to disable csrutil again and will continue with fixing python version.

I removed python2 installations I could find, more or less following this:

```
brew uninstall python@2
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
sudo rm -rf "/Applications/Python 2.7"
cd /usr/local/bin/
ls -l /usr/local/bin | grep '../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7' | awk '{print $9}' | tr -d @ | xargs rm
```

then I installed python2 through brew and it uses correct openssl:

```
~ brew install python@2
~ python -c "import urllib2,json; print(json.loads(urllib2.urlopen('https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check').read())['tls_version'])"
TLS 1.2
```

Comment: You should use some kind of virtualenv mechanism and not just blatantly delete stock Python as it may be used by other stuff... Also remember to tick your answer as solved if you are happy with it so that the question is closed.